# How to get dropdown list value from xlsx with phpspreadsheet

Tags: dropdown, xlsx, phpspreadsheet

i have to read dorpdown menu value form an xlsx file

[Xlsx dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ73K.png) ... so
i tried with

```
$inputFileName = 'file.xlsx';
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheet(2);

$validation = $sheet->getCell('F3')
->getDataValidation();
$test = $validation->getFormula1();
$test1 = $validation->getFormula2();
```

but didn't work,
someone can halo me?? thank you!